# Dynamically populate GraphSource through PopulateGraphSource method - RadDiagram

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, telerik, raddiagram

I am facing an issue where my graph is tree layout and looks fine initially. However, if I choose to change GraphSource upon user input/ clicks using `PopulateGraphSource` like in the OrgChart example, I get all the nodes stacked on top of each other with no links and all in corner.

I tried resetting graphSource by creating a new one

```
this.graphSource = new GraphSource();
```

I also tried to use the `Clear` method for `GraphSource`. Neither did solve the problem, I keep having the same issue.

I am using

```
ObservableCollection<Node> hierarchicalDataSource;
```

to fill up my GraphSource object.

All I do is create a new one and then call

```
PopulateGraphSource();
```

method.

Similar issues: [question in telerik support](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/silverlight/diagram/dynamically-change-graphsource-through-populategraphsource-method.aspx) , [telerik support different question](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/silverlight/diagram/refreshing-diagram-with-new-data.aspx#2707707)

Comment: Could you please provide more details about this issue? I mean may be some xaml and code behind or view models will be helpful to better understand the context of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try calling the Layout method on the diagram control. Here is a little fragment of code

```
TreeLayoutSettings settings = new TreeLayoutSettings()
        {
            TreeLayoutType = TreeLayoutType.TreeDown,
            VerticalSeparation = 60,
            HorizontalSeparation=30
        };

        if (this.diagram.Shapes.Count > 0)
        {
            settings.Roots.Add(this.diagram.Shapes[0]);
            this.diagram.Layout(LayoutType.Tree, settings);
            this.diagram.AutoFit();
            //this.diagram.Zoom = 1;
        }
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I was short in time and already switched to programmatically create the grid and assign graphsource